# Listing all indexes

Tags: sql-server, indexing, metadata, sysobjects

I'm wondering what the *simplest* way to list all indexes for all tables in a database is.

Should I call `sp_helpindex` for each table and store the results in a temp table, or is there an easier way?

Can anyone explain why constraints are stored in sysobjects but indexes are not?

Answer (score 37):

Here's an example of the kind of query you need:

```
select 
    i.name as IndexName, 
    o.name as TableName, 
    ic.key_ordinal as ColumnOrder,
    ic.is_included_column as IsIncluded, 
    co.[name] as ColumnName
from sys.indexes i 
join sys.objects o on i.object_id = o.object_id
join sys.index_columns ic on ic.object_id = i.object_id 
    and ic.index_id = i.index_id
join sys.columns co on co.object_id = i.object_id 
    and co.column_id = ic.column_id
where i.[type] = 2 
and i.is_unique = 0 
and i.is_primary_key = 0
and o.[type] = 'U'
--and ic.is_included_column = 0
order by o.[name], i.[name], ic.is_included_column, ic.key_ordinal
;
```

This one is somewhat specific to a certain purpose (I use it in a little C# app to find duplicate indexes and format the output so it's actually readable by a human).  But you could easily adapt it to your needs.

Comment: type 2 is non-clustered, any reason you've filtered out all the other index types? the question doesn't require it. ref https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173760%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 7):

You could reference [sysindexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190283.aspx)

Another trick is to look at the text of sp_helpindex to see how it reconstructs information from the underlying tables.

```
sp_helptext 'sp_helpindex'
```

I don't have a reference for this, but I believe constraints are not stored in sysobjects because they are a different kind of thing; sysindexes contains meta-data about objects in sysobjects.

Answer (score 5):

If you need more information, here is a nice SQL script, which I use from time to time:

```
DECLARE @TabName varchar(100)

CREATE TABLE #temp (
   TabName varchar(200), IndexName varchar(200), IndexDescr varchar(200), 
   IndexKeys varchar(200), IndexSize int
)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD LOCAL FOR
    SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'U'

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @TabName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #temp (IndexName, IndexDescr, IndexKeys)
        EXEC sp_helpindex @TabName

        UPDATE #temp SET TabName = @TabName WHERE TabName IS NULL

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @TabName
    END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur

DECLARE @ValueCoef int
SELECT @ValueCoef = low FROM Master.dbo.spt_values WHERE number = 1 AND type = N'E'

UPDATE #temp SET IndexSize = 
    ((CAST(sysindexes.used AS bigint) * @ValueCoef)/1024)/1024
        FROM sysobjects INNER JOIN sysindexes ON sysobjects.id = sysindexes.id
            INNER JOIN #temp T ON T.TabName = sysobjects.name AND T.IndexName = sysindexes.name

SELECT * FROM #temp
ORDER BY TabName, IndexName 

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a script that will return SQL statements to recreate all the indexes in a database.

```
SELECT ' CREATE ' +
       CASE 
            WHEN I.is_unique = 1 THEN ' UNIQUE '
            ELSE ''
       END +
       I.type_desc COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT + ' INDEX ' +
       I.name + ' ON ' +
       SCHEMA_NAME(T.schema_id) + '.' + T.name + ' ( ' +
       KeyColumns + ' )  ' +
       ISNULL(' INCLUDE (' + IncludedColumns + ' ) ', '') +
       ISNULL(' WHERE  ' + I.filter_definition, '') + ' WITH ( ' +
       CASE 
            WHEN I.is_padded = 1 THEN ' PAD_INDEX = ON '
            ELSE ' PAD_INDEX = OFF '
       END + ',' +
       'FILLFACTOR = ' + CONVERT(
           CHAR(5),
           CASE 
                WHEN I.fill_factor = 0 THEN 100
                ELSE I.fill_factor
           END
       ) + ',' +
       -- default value 
       'SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF ' + ',' +
       CASE 
            WHEN I.ignore_dup_key = 1 THEN ' IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON '
            ELSE ' IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF '
       END + ',' +
       CASE 
            WHEN ST.no_recompute = 0 THEN ' STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF '
            ELSE ' STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON '
       END + ',' +
       ' ONLINE = OFF ' + ',' +
       CASE 
            WHEN I.allow_row_locks = 1 THEN ' ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON '
            ELSE ' ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF '
       END + ',' +
       CASE 
            WHEN I.allow_page_locks = 1 THEN ' ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON '
            ELSE ' ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF '
       END + ' ) ON [' +
       DS.name + ' ] ' +  CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ' GO' [CreateIndexScript]
FROM   sys.indexes I
       JOIN sys.tables T
            ON  T.object_id = I.object_id
       JOIN sys.sysindexes SI
            ON  I.object_id = SI.id
            AND I.index_id = SI.indid
       JOIN (
                SELECT *
                FROM   (
                           SELECT IC2.object_id,
                                  IC2.index_id,
                                  STUFF(
                                      (
                                          SELECT ' , ' + C.name + CASE 
                                                                       WHEN MAX(CONVERT(INT, IC1.is_descending_key)) 
                                                                            = 1 THEN 
                                                                            ' DESC '
                                                                       ELSE 
                                                                            ' ASC '
                                                                  END
                                          FROM   sys.index_columns IC1
                                                 JOIN sys.columns C
                                                      ON  C.object_id = IC1.object_id
                                                      AND C.column_id = IC1.column_id
                                                      AND IC1.is_included_column = 
                                                          0
                                          WHERE  IC1.object_id = IC2.object_id
                                                 AND IC1.index_id = IC2.index_id
                                          GROUP BY
                                                 IC1.object_id,
                                                 C.name,
                                                 index_id
                                          ORDER BY
                                                 MAX(IC1.key_ordinal) 
                                                 FOR XML PATH('')
                                      ),
                                      1,
                                      2,
                                      ''
                                  ) KeyColumns
                           FROM   sys.index_columns IC2 
                                  --WHERE IC2.Object_id = object_id('Person.Address') --Comment for all tables
                           GROUP BY
                                  IC2.object_id,
                                  IC2.index_id
                       ) tmp3
            )tmp4
            ON  I.object_id = tmp4.object_id
            AND I.Index_id = tmp4.index_id
       JOIN sys.stats ST
            ON  ST.object_id = I.object_id
            AND ST.stats_id = I.index_id
       JOIN sys.data_spaces DS
            ON  I.data_space_id = DS.data_space_id
       JOIN sys.filegroups FG
            ON  I.data_space_id = FG.data_space_id
       LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT *
                FROM   (
                           SELECT IC2.object_id,
                                  IC2.index_id,
                                  STUFF(
                                      (
                                          SELECT ' , ' + C.name
                                          FROM   sys.index_columns IC1
                                                 JOIN sys.columns C
                                                      ON  C.object_id = IC1.object_id
                                                      AND C.column_id = IC1.column_id
                                                      AND IC1.is_included_column = 
                                                          1
                                          WHERE  IC1.object_id = IC2.object_id
                                                 AND IC1.index_id = IC2.index_id
                                          GROUP BY
                                                 IC1.object_id,
                                                 C.name,
                                                 index_id 
                                                 FOR XML PATH('')
                                      ),
                                      1,
                                      2,
                                      ''
                                  ) IncludedColumns
                           FROM   sys.index_columns IC2 
                                  --WHERE IC2.Object_id = object_id('Person.Address') --Comment for all tables
                           GROUP BY
                                  IC2.object_id,
                                  IC2.index_id
                       ) tmp1
                WHERE  IncludedColumns IS NOT NULL
            ) tmp2
            ON  tmp2.object_id = I.object_id
            AND tmp2.index_id = I.index_id
WHERE  I.is_primary_key = 0
       AND I.is_unique_constraint = 0
       --AND T.name NOT LIKE 'mt_%'
       --AND I.name NOT LIKE 'mt_%'
           --AND I.Object_id = object_id('Person.Address') --Comment for all tables
           --AND I.name = 'IX_Address_PostalCode' --comment for all indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a clear explanation why indexes are not stored in sys.objects. But I would like to contribute to find a simple way to list all indexes for all tables and views in a database. The following query retrieves all indexes including their type and also their object id and object type.

```
use /*Enter here your database*/
go
select A.Object_id,B.name,B.type,B.type_desc, A.index_id,A.type,A.type_desc
from sys.indexes A left join sys.objects B on A.object_id=B.object_id
where B.type = 'U' or B.type='V' /*filtering on U or V to retrieve tables and views only*/
order by B.name ASC /*Optional sorting*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written this code to iterate through all the databases in your server and push it to a table in a database named Maintenance. You should create this database first and then create a table in that database with the following fields:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DBCC_Stats](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DatabaseName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SchemaName] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [TableName] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [StatName] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [modification_counter] [bigint] NULL,
    [rows] [bigint] NULL,
    [rows_sampled] [bigint] NULL,
    [% Rows Sampled] [bigint] NULL,
    [last_updated] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [DateEntered] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DBCC_Stats] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DBCC_Stats] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_DBCC_Stats_DateEntered]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [DateEntered]
```

To use the stored procedure below you'd pass in the server name.
usp_Execute_Stats '[YourServerName]'

```
`CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Execute_Stats
    @ServerName varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @strSQL varchar(max)
SET @strSQL='USE ?
SELECT      ''' + '?' + ''' AS DatabaseName,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(obj.object_id) SchemaName, obj.name TableName,
           stat.name StatName, modification_counter,
            [rows], rows_sampled, rows_sampled* 100 / [rows] AS [% Rows Sampled],
            last_updated
FROM        ' + @ServerName + '.' + '?' + '.sys.objects AS obj
INNER JOIN  ' + @ServerName + '.' + '?' + '.sys.stats AS stat ON stat.object_id = obj.object_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_db_stats_properties(stat.object_id, stat.stats_id) AS sp
WHERE       obj.is_ms_shipped = 0
ORDER BY    modification_counter DESC'
INSERT INTO Maintenance.dbo.vwDBCC_Stats
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @strSQL
--Delete older logs
DELETE Maintenance.dbo.DBCC_Stats
    --WHERE DatabaseName IN('Master','Model','MSDB','TempDB')
    WHERE [DateEntered] < getdate()-14
END`
```